# using custom fonts on blackberry application

Tags: blackberry, java-me

I'm developing a BB app where I need to use some custom fonts. I was trying to load them as "statics"

```
public class MyFontTool
{

    public static FontFamily fontSolanoGothicMVBLt = Font.getDefault().getFontFamily();

    try {
        if (FontManager.getInstance().load("font/SolanoGothicMVB-Lt.ttf",
                "SolanoGothicMVB-Lt", FontManager.APPLICATION_FONT) == FontManager.SUCCESS) {
            fontSolanoGothicMVBLt = FontFamily
                    .forName("SolanoGothicMVB-Lt");
        }
    }
    catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

not sure if this is possible but when I run the application I got this message:

> Error Starting ... : Class 'net.rim.device.api.ui.FontManager' not found.

I'm using Blackberry SDK 5.0

Any idea why this doesn't work?

Comment: Which device or simulator are you **running** this on?  Is it a 5.0 device (or simulator)?

Comment: If you have compiled your application with BB Java SDK 5.0, then the application will run on a device or simulator with RIM OS 5.0, 6.x, 7.x. But it won't run on RIM OS 4.x. Check your device/simulator RIM OS version. To do this open `options/about` on your device/simulator screen.